# How can I loop from a data file to display content?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-theme

Data **can** display if I specify `{% assign member = site.data.members[page.author] %}` and insert `author: valuehere` in a page's frontmatter. It will not loop if I specify `{% for member in site.data.members %} ~~~ {{ member.name }} ~~~ {% endfor %}`

== members.yml

```
attorney1:
  birth_country: "United States of America"
  birth_city: "Paso Robles"
  birth_region: CA
  birth_zip: 93446
  birth_date: "05/1968"
  education: "Southeastern University: B.A. History – 2008, University of Florida Levin College of Law: Juris Doctor – 2001"
  image: attorney1.jpg
  nationality: "United States of America"
  name: "Attorney One Esq"
  first_name: "Attorney"
  last_name: "One"
  honorary: Esquire
  email: email@example.com
  home_country: "United States of America"
  home_city: "Ocala"
  home_region: "FL"
  home_zip: "34482"
  gender: Male
  permalink: "/lawyers/attorney1.html"
  ext: "02"
  practices: "Personal Injury &middot; Insurance Litigation"
  web: "Lawyer One Esq is a past member of the Hillsborough County Bar Association and Young Lawyers Division, the Lakeland Bar Association, and Emerge. Jon was also served on the Board of Directors for Tri-County Human services, which serves Polk, Hardee, and Highlands counties. Lawyer One Esq is currently a member of the Jacksonville Bar Association."
```

I've tried reformatting data file like this:

```
- author: attorney1
  name: "Attorney One"
~~~
```

Then recode author page like this:

```
---
layout: attorney
title: "Attorney One"
crumbtitle: "Attorney One"
permalink: "/lawyers/attorney1.html"
jsontype: lawyer
genre: Law
headline: "Affordable Marion County Legal Representation"
author: attorney1
---
{% assign author = site.data.members | where: "author", "{{page.author}}" %}
<!-- Main -->
<article id="main">
  <header class="special container">
    <span class="icon fas fa-user-circle"></span>
    <h2>About {{ author.name }}</h2>
    {{ author.web | markdownify }}
  </header>
  <!-- One -->
```

The goal is to be able to use a for loop and to pull data for an author page. If I format data file like:

```
attorney1:
    name: "Attorney one"
```

the author page works with `{% assign author = site.data.members[page.author] %}` and breaks the for-loop.

Comment: Do you care about the keys? (`"attorney1"` in this example) Since the *for*-loop might loop through the key/value pairs. Could you try `for member in site.data.members.values` instead and see if that works?

Comment: @3limin4t0r there are other keys in this data file. Just stuck! It works calling a specific key. Just not in a for loop.

Comment: @3limin4t0r if I switch data file format to `- author: attorney1` with values 2 spaces below, the loop works and the author page stops working for `{% assign member = site.data.members[page.author] %}`

Comment: @3limin4t0r `{% assign author = site.data.members | where: "author", "{{page.author}}" %}` doesn't work, either, on the author page.

Comment: Vote for my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To successfully *iterate* through a given list, all you need is a properly structured data.

For `{% for member in site.data.members %}` to loop properly, `site.data.members` has to be an *array of members*. But from the info you have posted, it looks like the resulting data is a `Hash` (or *dictionary*) of key-value pairs instead of an `Array`.

### Investigation

To confirm, you may simply "inspect" the data first. Insert the following snippet into your template to get a JSON representation of your data:

```
<pre>
{{ site.data.members | inspect }}
</pre>
```

To iterate successfully, **the resulting JSON** should begin and end with square brackets (`[`, `]`):

```js
[
  {
    "attorney1": {
      "birth_country": "United States of America",
      "birth_city": "Paso Robles"
    }
  },
  {
    "attorney2": {
      "birth_country": "United States of America",
      "birth_city": "Paso Robles"
    }
  },
]
```

But instead, your `members.yml` would yield something similar to:

```js
{
  "attorney1": {
    "birth_country": "United States of America",
    "birth_city": "Paso Robles"
  },
  "attorney2": {
    "birth_country": "United States of America",
    "birth_city": "Paso Robles"
  }
}
```

### Solutions

#### Single file

If you'd like to have all the attorney info in one YAML file, then the structure would be:

```yaml
# _data/members.yml

- attorney1:
    birth_country: "United States of America"
    birth_city: "Paso Robles"
- attorney2:
    birth_country: "United States of America"
    birth_city: "Paso Robles"
```

#### Individual files

Or if you'd like organize individual info separately:

```yaml
# _data/members/attorney1.yml

birth_country: "United States of America"
birth_city: "Paso Robles"
```

```yaml
# _data/members/attorney2.yml

birth_country: "United States of America"
birth_city: "Paso Robles"
```

---

### Selection

To select a particular dataset based on a given key, you can pass the data and key to the `where` filter and the `first` or `last` filters:

```
{% assign member = site.data.members | where: 'author', page.author | first %}
```

With the above, first another array of members is generated where `member.author` equals `page.author` and then the very first entry is extracted via the `first` filter.

Comment: I read https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/ I have the single YML file your example  and exampled in the docs. The loop works. But, `{% assign member = site.data.members[page.author]` will not work even with the frontmatter defining which lawyer to output.

Comment: Again, use the inspect filter to "check" the data object. `{{ site.data.members | inspect }}` and `{{ page.author | inspect }}` should give you the necessary insights.

Comment: ```---
layout: attorney
author: attorney2
---
{% assign member = site.data.members[page.author] %}

<!-- Main -->
<article id="main">
  <header class="special container">
    <span class="icon fas fa-user-circle"></span>
    <h2>About {{ member.name }}</h2>
    {{ member.web | markdownify }}
{{ page.author | inspect }}{{ site.data.members | inspect }} 
``` shows attorney2 as author and the jsonify [{~~}] values of datafile.

Comment: `{{ site.data.members[page.author] | inspect | jsonify }} {{ page.author | inspect }}` produces `"nil" "attorney2"` on /lawyers/attorney2.html

Comment: I've edited the answer with the solution to extract a member based on given key. Basically, you're trying to do two different things with one data: *iterate and render each member* and *select a particular member and render that*. So there are two different types of solutions

Comment: Please +1 my question?